# Unable clone Bitbucket repo using Git 2.13.1.2 on Windows

Tags: git, ssl, bitbucket, clone

I have a Bitbucket account. I created a private repository and install Git on Windows machine. While I am trying to clone the repository using the following command

```
git clone http://username@git.yoox.net/scm/~username/reponame.git
```

it throws error:

> cloning into 'reponame'...  fatal:unable to access
>   'http://username@git.yoox.net/scm/~username/reponame.git/':SSL
>   certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

After searching (Google) two solutions i found are

1. Disable SSL
2. Add certificate.

I found https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/phkelley/2014/01/20/adding-a-corporate-or-self-signed-certificate-authority-to-git-exes-store/ this link but it won't suite my scenario.so, I disabled the ssl with no options left for me using the following command

```
git config --global http.sslVerify false
```

After this i have run the same clone command which i have done previously,then i'm getting the following error

> cloning into 'reponame'... warning: redirecting to
>   https://git.yoox.net/scm/~username/reponame.git/  fatal:remote error:
>   Repository not found requested repository does not exist, or you do
>   not have permission to access it.

Observations: When I'm cloning after disabling SSL, while the console is there at `cloning into 'reponame'...` I able to see the repository folder of mine but immediately it is vanishing.

Comment: You should format your question carefully.

Comment: Thanks to you for the suggestion. -@DoNhuVy

Comment: `Repository not found requested repository does not exist, or you do not have permission to access it.` means what it says: either your URL is wrong (repo doesn't exist) or you can't access it (wrong username/password/SSH key/permissions)

Comment: I have created the repository and i'm the owner(admin), i have checked the url again and it is correct @Adrian

Comment: Have you checked your credentials? If you're using SSH, are you sure it's using a private key associated with a public key configured on the repo?

Comment: No, i'm not using ssh @Adrian

Comment: Have you triple-checked the username & password it's using?

Comment: yes, yesterday i gave them....today it is not asking...if you check my url there is vpn in between my system and bitbucket and  i have given correct credentials @Adrian

Comment: Very much thanks to you... @DoNhuVy